# What's the difference between "cannot find the file specified" and "could not find the file specified"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What's the difference between "cannot find the file specified" and "could not find the file specified"?

I've seen both of them when a software is reporting an error. What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of an error or result reported by software, there is no difference.
(I assume that ' file the file specified' is intended to be 'find the file specified'.)